# jupyter with multiple version of python 3 (3.6 and 3.7) choosing the wrong site-packages

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pipenv, pyenv

I have been banging my head at my desk for 3 days now and I am not sure what to do about this issue, so please if you have any idea of what is going on let me know.

**Issue:** When I am running a globally installed (outside of the virtual environment) jupyter notebook with a registered kernel (ipykernel installed in the virtual env) where the python3 -V of the virtual environment is 3.6.4 and the global python3 -V is 3.7.0, the jupyter notebook (is ran from wihin the active venv) crashes when I activate the venv kernel because it is trying to pick up site packages from the global python 3.7.0

```
[I 11:11:13.221 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/cap/Desktop/Projects/lastresort
[I 11:11:13.221 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 11:11:13.221 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 11:11:13.221 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=cc92b513df1e586ce592bfc4fe641b9f2d76fdde480c6f07
[I 11:11:13.221 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 11:11:13.222 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=cc92b513df1e586ce592bfc4fe641b9f2d76fdde480c6f07&token=cc92b513df1e586ce592bfc4fe641b9f2d76fdde480c6f07
[I 11:11:13.438 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[I 11:11:16.385 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 2ad09f31-36f6-48cf-b859-7f78fdb6adb8
[I 11:11:17.014 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 2ad09f31-36f6-48cf-b859-7f78fdb6adb8
[I 11:11:19.398 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for 2ad09f31-36f6-48cf-b859-7f78fdb6adb8:cda1e6c165f3482482d80df7d2664e9b
[I 11:11:19.609 NotebookApp] Kernel shutdown: 2ad09f31-36f6-48cf-b859-7f78fdb6adb8
[I 11:11:19.630 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 9b90f202-97bf-43b1-ba50-64d6a1323405
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cap/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/cap/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_client/connect.py", line 23, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/utils/sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 26, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'
```

As you can see from the few lines above, it is calling the wrong site-packages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cap/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/cap/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_5/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
```

This is my setup:

- pyenv for managing multiple versions of python
- pipenv for virtualenvs (still not super happy with this one)

How I set it up:

1. Install global python (I don't like messing around with pyenv for my default python, I keep to the most up to date version)

   `> brew install python3 # This install 3.7.0`
2. Install pyenv

   `> brew install pyenv`
3. Install python 3.6.4 (I need this for tensorflow)

   `> pyenv install 3.6.4`
4. Install pipenv (I am not using the pip installer here)

   `> brew install pipenv`
5. Create a project (I have a WORKON_HOME setup so my .venvs get
   created in my ~/.venvs)

   ```
     > cd Projects
     > mkdire test_project
     > cd test_project
     > pipenv --python 3.6.4 #create the virtual env
   ```
6. Launch the virtual env

   ```
     > pipenv shell 
     > python3 -V
     > Python 3.6.4 # I have validated in another shell that global is still 3.7

     > pyenv which python3
     > /Users/cap/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/bin/python3
   ```
7. Install ipykernel and setup

   ```
     > pipenv install ipykernel
     > ipython kernel install --user --name=lastresort-yyl8tfk8 --display-name "Python (lastresort-yyl8tfk8)"
   ```
8. Check if jupyter sees the new kernel (Note: I am still in the venv)

   ```
     > jupyter kernelspec list
     > lastresort-yyl8tfk8    /Users/cap/Library/Jupyter/kernels/lastresort-yyl8tfk8
   ```
9. Run the jupyter notebook and select the kernel
   The jotebook runs fine, but when I get in and select the Python (lastresort-yyl8tfk8), the kernel restarts to load the lastresort-yyl8tfk8 kernel and I get the error from above, where it is getting confused with site-packages from 3.7.

I tried a bunch of things with paths. I also even resorted to ipython profile changes such as in here: [iptyhon profile virtual env](https://gist.github.com/henriquebastos/270cff100cb303f3d74370489022446b)

I really need some help at least with a direction of how to solve this...

My ultimate goal is simple:
Be able to have multiple versions of python with corresponding ipykernels that I can run from their virtual environments after registering them with jupyter where the jupyter install is global. In this way I can keep my code and notebook in their project folders with venvs for packages. It is pretty simple actually, I just don't know what I am messing up.

**Thank you all in advance!**

**UPDATE:**
I just verified that if I remove the global jupyter notebook and install it in the venv, it works properly. I did not expect it not to, but still.

**UPDATE:**
It seems to be some PYTHONPATH shenanigans but I don't know how to fix it.

**UPDATE:**
Tried to run using python -m as suggested in comments, but it produced the same results. For some reason when I call the jupyter notebook (installed outside of the virtual environment) with an activated virtual environment (with correctly set python3.6 in ipython in there) it does not call the right 3.6 site packages.

I have seen so many people using that setup. I really don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Try running commands as runnable modules, with the `-m` switch: `python -m pip install <package>`, `python -m jupyter notebook` etc. Once you got the correct Python version going, this will give you a better chance that the correct pip, jupyter and so on are used.

Comment: If there is a PYTHONPATH set, try unsetting it (perhaps after copying its value to a text file as backup). With the above commands, you shouldn't need a PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Trying those right now. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same problem when connecting to a jupyter console. If I however switch to the venv and do `jupyter kernel --kernl=<id>`, I can then connect with the provided run time kernel to the console.

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR

For me it worked installing `jupyter` in the virtual enviroment created by `pipenv` with the following command:

```
pipenv run pip install jupyter
```

## Too Short, Wanna Read!

I had the same problem with python 3 versions so I started using `pipenv` as you show, with a simple `Pipfile` configuration as follows:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
numpy = "*"
pandas = "*"
matplotlib = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

I thought that, as I specified python version to 3.7 in that config file, whenever I wanted to run `pipenv run jupyter notebook`, the kernel would be running under Python 3.7...
But when imported the librares indicated there from the notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I got the "non module installed error"
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'`

And then in the same notebook, I checked in which version was the kernel running with the following code:

```
import sys

print(sys.version)
```

The output showed me that it was running under Python 3.6, so in that vesion I didn't have those modules installed, cause `pipenv` was intalling them for 3.7 version.

So I tried installing again jupyter but this time under the virtual enviroment created by `pipenv`, using the `run` command and `pip` tool:

```
pipenv run pip install jupyter
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

To make `pipenv` use the `Pipfile` you want when running it from any path you want, you should add to your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` the following env variable:

```
export PIPENV_PIPFILE="<path_to_the_Pipefile_you_want>"
```

Otherwise, `pipenv` will try to use a `Pipefile` from the path where it is being run.